# Python Webdriver unable to locate the correct button using Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am having some trouble finding the correct Xpath syntax for a button.
There are 2 Add buttons on the page.  There is an Add button below Reports.
There is an Add button below Projects.
I want to find the one below Projects but I am finding the one that is below Reports.

I have tried the following Xpaths, these find the add button below the span class Reports:

```
//button[div[. = 'Add...']]
//div[@class="gwt-HTML" and contains(text(), "Add...")]
e.g. driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[div[. = 'Add...']])
```

I want to find the Add... button below the span class Projects.
I can find the Projects span class with the following Xpath.  I don't know how to continue the Xpath and find the Add... button.

```
//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel" and contains(text(), 'Projects')]
```

The HTML snippet as follows:

```
    <div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 5px;">
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel" style="font-weight: bold; color: black; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 20px;">Reports</span>
    <div class="GAT4PNUMP">
    <button class="gwt-Button" type="button">
        <div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 2px;">
        <div class="gwt-HTML" style="margin-left: 15px;">Add...</div>
    </button>
    <button class="gwt-Button" type="button" disabled="">
    <button class="gwt-Button" type="button" disabled="">
    <div class="GAT4PNUMP">
    <button class="gwt-Button" type="button" title="Run the selected reports" disabled="">
    <button class="gwt-Button" type="button" title="View the selected report" disabled="">
    <button class="gwt-Button workspacebuttontext130" type="button" title="Conditional report" disabled="">Conditional report ▼</button>
    <div class="GAT4PNUMP">
    <select class="gwt-ListBox" style="height: 20px; margin-right: 5px;" disabled="">
</div>  

<div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 5px;">
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel" style="font-weight: bold; color: black; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 20px;">Projects</span>
    <div class="GAT4PNUMP">
    <button class="gwt-Button" type="button">
        <div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 2px;">
        <div class="gwt-HTML" style="margin-left: 15px;">Add...</div>
    </button>
    <button class="gwt-Button" type="button" disabled="">
    <button class="gwt-Button workspacebuttontext75" type="button" title="Delete" disabled="">Delete </button>
    <div class="GAT4PNUMP">
    <button class="gwt-Button workspacebuttontext60" type="button" title="Import to the selected project" disabled="">Import...</button>
    <button class="gwt-Button workspacebuttontext60" type="button" title="Export from the selected project" disabled="">Export...</button>
    <button class="gwt-Button workspacebuttontext75" type="button" title="Upgrade the selected project" disabled="">Upgrade...</button>
    <button class="gwt-Button workspacebuttontext60" type="button" title="Refresh the selected project" disabled="">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

What Xpath can i use to locate Add... which is in below the span class Projects?
Thanks.

Comment: if you use Firefox browser you can install Selenium IDE add-on and simply get unique selector (Xpath, css_selector...) for required page element

Comment: I have IDE 2.9.0 installed.  Where in the IDE is the option for unique selector?  If i record the click in the Target field I can see in the drop down xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[35].  Is this the selector?

Comment: well, yeah. you can use it to press your button as `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[35]").click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to the developer and she said the button is a sibling of the project span class.  I should use following-sibling to get to the button.  I have managed to get it to work now.
This is my XPATH:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel" and contains(text(), 'Projects')]/following-sibling::*/div[@class="gwt-HTML" and contains(text(), 'Add...')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(.//span[text()='Projects' and @class='gwt-InlineLabel]/button[text()='Add...'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  There is also a span class projects title further up the html tree.  It is going to that one.  If i can use //span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel" and contains(text(), 'Projects')] and add the button in here somehow that would be great

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried it, it still doesn't work.  If i remove /button[text()='Add...']) it will find the Projects span and highlight it.  I don't know why i cannot get to the button below it. /button should go to the tag below the span class tag.  Not sure why it doesn't go.

Comment: can you post the url of the page and ill try it out?

Comment: It is not a public facing url.  The website is only accessed from within the company.  I think I have worked out the Xpath now using following-sibling.  I am just going to try out my code then I will paste the answer.

Comment: The following Xpath works: //span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel" and contains(text(), 'Projects')]/following-sibling::*/div[@class="gwt-HTML" and contains(text(), 'Add...')]

Answer (score 0):

Simply open the website in Chrome, right-click on the button and then `inspect element`. On the bottom half of the window you should now see the page's source. Verify that the required line is highlighted and right-click on it, then choose  "copy xpath". Then just paste it to `driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_string_from_chrome")`